# Like Python, is there any way in Java to read/write without closing buffer?

Tags: java, python, buffer

1) Like Python, is there any way in Java to read/write without closing the buffer?
As http://blog.lerner.co.il/dont-use-python-close-files-answer-depends article explains, by deleting the object, or manipulating the data size in comparison to the buffer size, we can still get the job done without closing the buffer. What's the general intuition/theory behind this concept? How is it possible? Why exactly should we close the buffer? 
2) Could I rephrase/add to my question? Please enlighten.

Comment: It's really not clear what "buffer" you refer to. Sure you can open eg. a file or network connection in Java and not close it to keep writing into it if that's what you mean.

Comment: you can use the try (stream) syntax to automatically close the stream. Stream must be closed either automatically or explicitly.

Comment: @JessePinkman I do not know python but just curious what happens when a method like println or any handler of line throws an error. Will the file still be closed?

Comment: `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` implement `AutoCloseable`, so if they are wrapped in [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) they are automatically closed after the closing brackets of the try as in `try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) { whatever }`.  This is very similar to the pattern used in Python's with-statement.

Comment: @gagansingh: Yes, the file is still closed in Python and Java provided you used the language appropriate way of opening the file.  In Python that's using `with open(filename, mode) as f:` and in java its using a try-with-resources as shown in my prior comment or as in gagan singh's answer.  Python's magic is accomplished by having the object implement `__atenter__()` and `__atexit__()` and in java it's done by implementing `AutoCloseable`.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to your python code. file is automatically closed.

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    stream.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: I think it's important to mention that the Interface [Stream<T>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) implements Interface [AutoClosable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html):  "The close() method of an AutoCloseable object is called automatically when exiting a try-with-resources block for which the object has been declared in the resource specification header. This construction ensures prompt release, avoiding resource exhaustion exceptions and errors that may otherwise occur."  This explains the magic.